SpringBoot AOT unable to find context when run in JavaFX
I am attempting to use SpringBoot along with JavaFX.  To do this, the main class extends the JavaFX Application.  I then start the spring context from the JavaFx thread during the init method.  This works as expected for running and building a jar.
When attempting to use mvn native:compile -Pnative via the native maven plugin, the following error comes up:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No application context available after calling main method of 'com.example.JavaFxNative.problemDemo.ProblemDemoApplication'. Does it run a SpringApplication?
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationAotProcessor$AotProcessorHook.run(SpringApplicationAotProcessor.java:120)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationAotProcessor.prepareApplicationContext(SpringApplicationAotProcessor.java:60)
        at org.springframework.context.aot.ContextAotProcessor.doProcess(ContextAotProcessor.java:83)
        at org.springframework.context.aot.ContextAotProcessor.doProcess(ContextAotProcessor.java:49)
        at org.springframework.context.aot.AbstractAotProcessor.process(AbstractAotProcessor.java:82)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationAotProcessor.main(SpringApplicationAotProcessor.java:80)

Is there a good way to use AOT with JavaFx and springboot where the spring context is created by JavaFX?
See the below code and config files to reproduce the behavior.
package com.example.JavaFxNative.problemDemo;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ProblemDemoApplication extends Application {

    protected ConfigurableApplicationContext springContext;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {
        springContext = configurableApplicationContext();

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        stage.show();

    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        springContext.close();
    }

    private ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext(){
        SpringApplicationBuilder springApplicationBuilder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(ProblemDemoApplication.class);
        String[] args = getParameters().getRaw().toArray(String[]::new);
        return springApplicationBuilder.run(args);
    }
}

The pom.xml can be found below:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example.JavaFxNative</groupId>
    <artifactId>problemDemo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>problemDemo</name>
    <description>Demo for JavaFx and SpringBoot native</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>21.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

And the module-info:
open module demo{
    requires javafx.base;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires spring.boot;
    requires spring.boot.autoconfigure;
    requires spring.context;
}


Can you get a pure SpringBoot app to work after building a native image?

Yes.  A pure SpringBoot app successfully compiled to a native image.  I had to switch from modular to non-modular, but it worked.
However, switching JavaFX from modular to non-modular had no change, the same exception comes up.  It seems like the spring AOT code is getting the context in a way which is not compatible with JavaFX.  I was hoping to be able to provide it with a hit or something on how to retrieve the context on application start.

@LouisCreager You might want to create a pull request with the native compiling on this repository: https://github.com/davidweber411/javafx-JavaFxSpringBootMavenApp :)

@DavidWeber, are you able to get that repo to native compile?  I cloned it and ran into the same error as I saw above:
Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.2.4:process-aot

@LouisCreager No, unfortunately not. But if you get it to work, I would appreciate it, If you create a pull request in the repo. :) Maybe I'll give it another chance tomorrow.

@LouisCreager Take a look at Gluon. They have a plugin for native compiling. But only "fxml" and "controls" modules are working, according to their docs.
